# Defining advice for cider-interactive-eval for evil compatibility

Tags: evil, advice, cider

Cider offers very useful debugger for clojure code. Once you enter the debugger, you can step through it with keys like (n)ext, (o)ut, etc., [like so](http://endlessparentheses.com/cider-debug-a-visual-interactive-debugger-for-clojure.html). Using evil, the problem is that if I enter this debugger in normal-state, those keypresses will never make it to cider-debug, as evil interprets them according to its own keymap.

One way to reconcile this would be to automatically enter insert state when `cider-interactive-eval` (how you enter the debugger) is called *and* `cider--debug-mode` is active.

Here's how I imagine it would be, but it doesn't work yet. How can I improve this?

```
(defadvice cider-interactive-eval (after enter-insert-for-dbg activate)
  "When cider-eval takes you to a dbg session, enter insert-state."
  (when (and (bound-and-true-p cider--debug-mode)
             (eq evil-state 'normal))
    (evil-insert 1)))

(ad-activate 'cider-interactive-eval)
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the initial mode tho `emacs-state` (or `insert-state`)?  `(add-to-list 'evil-emacs-state-modes 'cider--debug-mode)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to add `cider--debug-mode` to the `evil-insert-state-modes` list so that you automatically enter insert state when the debugger is triggered.  I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
(add-to-list 'evil-insert-state-modes 'cider--debug-mode)
```

I haven't dug into why this isn't working, but for the time being I'm using the `cider--debug-mode-hook` which is called whenever you enter or leave the mode.

```
(defun my-cider-debug-toggle-insert-state ()
  (if cider--debug-mode    ;; Checks if you're entering the debugger   
      (evil-insert-state)  ;; If so, turn on evil-insert-state
    (evil-normal-state)))  ;; Otherwise, turn on normal-state


(add-hook 'cider--debug-mode-hook 'my-cider-debug-toggle-insert-state)
```

This assumes you want to be in normal-state whenever you exit the debugger.

Comment: Thank you, it makes much more sense to add to the specific hook rather than to add an advice around every time cider eval is called.

Comment: Adivising SEEMS like something that could be useful but I haven't actually used it because It's more easily implemented with a hook instead.  It's also recommended to use hooks over advising when you have the choice between the two.  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AdviceVsHooks